# Sprite Kit Overlap lag with xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, collision

So I am trying to just get a feel of how Sprite Kit works, and one thing that I cannot figure out is why my demo lags when multiple versions of the same sprite over lap each other.

Basically what I do is I made a class that inherits SKSpriteNode, and on init I set the following properties

```
    marioCategory = 1 << 1;
    wallCategory = 1 << 2;
    platformCategory = 1 << 3;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
    self.physicsBody.density = 1.0;
    self.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
    self.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
    self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = marioCategory;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  platformCategory ;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =   wallCategory  ;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    self.name = @"Mario";
```

Then I add all these "Mario"'s into an SKNode as its children,  then I add this Node to the scene.  (Adding the children directly to the scene does not add perfomance);

What I think it is doing is an extensive check to see if the overlapping marios are colliding or contacting, even though the contactTest bit mask says to only check for walls.

Any help to determine what step I am missing would really be appreciated, thanks.

This has been tested on an iPhone 5 btw.

Here are how I have about 40 platforms setup on screen, all are 16x16,even Mario

```
    node.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
    node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.size];
    node.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
    node.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
    node.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
    node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0  ;
    node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0 ;
    node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

Comment: Are you NSlogging anything in contact delegate methods?

Comment: the delegate methods aren't even being called when 2 Marios overlap, only when it hits the wall, which is what I want

Comment: how many "multiple versions" overlapping at the same time?

Comment: I have 30 on the screen,  but its hard to tell when lag is actually happening,  it looks like when about 6 or more are overlapping each other

Comment: I just watched it, Lag is bad when there are 14 on the screen, with two sets of 7 sprites overlapping

Comment: just performed another test, I place a mario on the screen, then I place another one directly on top of it, and performance died.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your sprite? Do you set the xScale and/or yScale properties? I just added 50 sprites on top of each other and my FPS is around 60. The sprites' collision and contact bits are set to the edge loop's category.

Comment: the sprites are set to exactly how I have shown them in my question, nothing more, the sprites themselves are 16x16,  if it helps there are about 40 platforms on the screen also 16x16 set up in the edit above

Comment: So I made it with 1 platform and 52 marios, with 2 node containers, one for platform, one for marios, and performance starts to drop, now  I don't ever envision 52 marios on the screen, but I do need about 30, but as I add more platforms, the number of allowable marios decrease

Comment: So i switched it to edge with 2 points and it improved,  but i cant have all my objects using this,  this is an obvious performance issue on apples part, ill submit a bug report to them and have them look at it